# ESLint --fix causes prettier line break errors after prettier 2.3

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I'm in the process of updating prettier to version 2.3. After the update, my assignments' line break formatting is updated on save as expected (see [the release post](https://prettier.io/blog/2021/05/09/2.3.0.html#format-assignments-more-consistently-10222httpsgithubcomprettierprettierpull10222-10643httpsgithubcomprettierprettierpull10643-10672httpsgithubcomprettierprettierpull10672-by-thorn0httpsgithubcomthorn0-10158httpsgithubcomprettierprettierpull10158-by-sosukesuzukihttpsgithubcomsosukesuzuki)).

However, when I run `eslint`, these new line breaks causes errors. Running `eslint --fix` "fixes" the line breaks, which causes prettier to complain. This starts the cycle all over.

Both errors from `eslint` (i.e. after running prettier and after running `eslint --fix`) are `eslint(prettier/prettier)` errors.

Any ideas on how to get eslint and prettier to work together after the prettier 2.3 would be appreciated!

.eslintrc.js

```js
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    // other extensions
    'prettier',
    // other extensions
  ],
  plugins: [
    // other plugins
    'prettier',
    // other plugins
  ],
  rules: {
    // other rules
    'prettier/prettier': ['error', { endOfLine: 'auto' }],
    // other rules
  },
}
```